# Get depth from Kinect sensor in gazebo simulator

Tags: ros, gazebo, kinect, turtlebot, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to find a specific pixel's depth of `/depth/image_raw` topic that is published by Kinect sensor mounted on **Turtlebot** robot.

It's what I get: [www.uppic.com/do.php?img=97090](http://www.uppic.com/do.php?img=97090)) (Sorry I have not enough karma to upload image.

It's what I see in **rviz**: [www.uppic.com/do.php?img=97092](http://www.uppic.com/do.php?img=97092)

How can I fix it to get depth of pixels?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/90696/get-depth-from-kinect-sensor-in-gazebo-simulator/) by [maysamsh](https://answers.ros.org/users/4226/maysamsh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 139 on 2013-10-14

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [psei](https://answers.ros.org/users/6031/psei/) on 2013-10-15**:
Hi, I am having trouble understanding your question. What does the first picture actually show and what do you want to do with the depth information?

The second picture looks goot btw, so I think your sensor does work correct.

**Comment by [maysamsh](https://answers.ros.org/users/4226/maysamsh/) on 2013-10-15**:
I want to find distance of specific pixels

**Comment by [psei](https://answers.ros.org/users/6031/psei/) on 2013-10-15**:
I guess then you should take a look at the pointcloud topic that comes from the camera. It should contain distance information for every pixel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Heres a function someone else on this board someone gave me. I'd also added the code that I used for my node.

The node subscribes to the image stream and for every image, prints the depth at 100, 320. It's not the most beautiful code but it works :)

```
#include <image_transport/image_transport.h>

typedef union U_FloatParse {
    float float_data;
    unsigned char byte_data[4];
} U_FloatConvert;

int ReadDepthData(unsigned int height_pos, unsigned int width_pos, sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr depth_image)
{
    // If position is invalid
    if ((height_pos >= depth_image->height) || (width_pos >= depth_image->width))
        return -1;
    int index = (height_pos*depth_image->step) + (width_pos*(depth_image->step/depth_image->width));
    // If data is 4 byte floats (rectified depth image)
    if ((depth_image->step/depth_image->width) == 4) {
        U_FloatConvert depth_data;
        int i, endian_check = 1;
        // If big endian
        if ((depth_image->is_bigendian && (*(char*)&endian_check != 1)) ||  // Both big endian
           ((!depth_image->is_bigendian) && (*(char*)&endian_check == 1))) { // Both lil endian
            for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                depth_data.byte_data[i] = depth_image->data[index + i];
            // Make sure data is valid (check if NaN)
            if (depth_data.float_data == depth_data.float_data)
                return int(depth_data.float_data*1000);
            return -1;  // If depth data invalid
        }
        // else, one little endian, one big endian
        for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
            depth_data.byte_data[i] = depth_image->data[3 + index - i];
        // Make sure data is valid (check if NaN)
        if (depth_data.float_data == depth_data.float_data)
            return int(depth_data.float_data*1000);
        return -1;  // If depth data invalid
    }
    // Otherwise, data is 2 byte integers (raw depth image)
   int temp_val;
   // If big endian
   if (depth_image->is_bigendian)
       temp_val = (depth_image->data[index] << 8) + depth_image->data[index + 1];
   // If little endian
   else
       temp_val = depth_image->data[index] + (depth_image->data[index + 1] << 8);
   // Make sure data is valid (check if NaN)
   if (temp_val == temp_val)
       return temp_val;
   return -1;  // If depth data invalid
}

// Image Callback
void imageCallback(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& image) {
    int depth = ReadDepthData(100, 320, image); // Width = 640, Height = 480
    ROS_INFO("Depth: %d", depth);
}

//*** Main ***//
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ros::init(argc, argv, "imagegrab");
    ros::NodeHandle n;
    printf("READY to get image\n");
    image_transport::ImageTransport it(n);
    image_transport::Subscriber sub = it.subscribe("/camera/depth/image_raw", 1, imageCallback);
    ros::spin();
    return 0;
}
```

---

Originally posted by [Alkaros](https://answers.ros.org/users/6169/alkaros/) with karma: 103 on 2013-10-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PKumars](https://answers.ros.org/users/25000/pkumars/) on 2016-02-17**:
what if I want to subscribe both RGB and depth image at a time and then process both images simultaneously to get x,y,z in real-time? I'm trying to get position of a ball using Kinect in ROS_Indigo.